# AWS ELB with EC2 instances in different regions

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

AWS ElasticLoadBalancer (ELB) can distribute the traffic between multiple EC2 instances that are in the [different availability zones of the same region](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11424481/4636715).

Is it possible to back **AWS ELB with EC2 instances from different regions**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to back AWS ELB with EC2 instances from different regions?

To my understanding ELB can't do that.

Note that there is a good reason - introduced latency across regions as opposed to AZ latency. However, you could mimic something like that using Route53 or any other DNS that supports GSLB (Global Server Load Balancing) or similar approach.

Comment: Yes, apparently there is no way to implement cross-region load balancer. Plus, that task seems to delegated deliberately to Route53. I am not fond of pushing at this point. Route 53 is ok also, thanks!

Comment: @Const though probably a bad idea, an Application Load Balancer should be able to do this over VPC peering.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Agreed, however, original question was related to ELB options and answer tried to stay around that.

Comment: More details on the Route53 approach if you go that way - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/latency-based-multi-region-routing-now-available-for-aws/